# Easeljs performance drop?

Tags: canvas, easeljs

I've been playing with easeljs and I've found the performances starts to drop. In my example Chrome takes about 3s to get to this point, and Safari takes 25s, Firefox is all over the place.

**Questions:**

1. *am I doing something wrong*?
2. *or is this the performance hit I should expect from easeljs*?

**Example**
To demonstrate the performance hit I am experiencing, I created a simple circle redraw animation on a loop, but the framerate quickly begins to drop. If I revert to pure canvas API calls then it regains the performance.

Below is the crucial snippet from my redraw that chooses the method to draw the circle:

```
if ( counter.fps > 60) {
    circle.graphics.beginFill('green')
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0, w / 10)
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    stage.update();
} else {    
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(circle.x, circle.y, w / 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = "darkred";
    context.fill();
}
```

See this jsfiddle for a demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/AshCoolman/5xYxM/9/

**Variations I have tried with similar results**:

- requestAnimationFrame (and a pollyfill)
- Slower fps

**(Rough) timeline of performance** (OSX 10.8.2 on mid2012 macbook air)

*Chrome v26.0.1410.43*

- 0-3s = 90fps
- 3s = fps start to drop
- 6s = fps hits 60fps

*Safari v6.0.2 (8536.26.17)*

- 0-20s = 90fps
- 20s = fps start to drop
- 35s = fps hits 60fps

*Firefox v20*

- fsFiddle hosted: totally erratic
- locally hosted: Much like Chromes performance but much more erratic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EaselJS graphics are retained, so each frame you are adding another circle definition to `Graphics` queue. So, after 1000 "redraw" calls, it is drawing 1000 circles each time.

Use `Graphics.clear()` to reset the draw queue, or just draw the circle once & move the corresponding Shape (recommended).

Here's a modified version of your Fiddle, that gets a solid 99fps for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/5xYxM/13/

Comment: +1 for good catch of OP's glitch.  BTW, are you actually associated with CreateJS. If so, I like your code and good to meet you!

Comment: Thanks! Nice to meet you too @markE. I'm the original creator of the libraries (Grant Skinner) - glad you're liking them.